# The phrase "caught flat footed"

Tags: slang

Is it professionally okay to use the term "caught flat-footed"?

Comment: I thought the expression was _caught wrong-footed_. That is to say to be caught off guard with one's balance on the wrong foot (as in soccer, or such). [Obama](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=i_3pyWxQrNUC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=caught+wrongfooted+wiki&source=bl&ots=07AWH7Ix1n&sig=xDZEjlHbdI1YZv5DnwtXqVIizDs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9tJ_ek5rbAhUB3aQKHS1EAXgQ6AEIUzAE#v=onepage&q=caught%20wrongfooted%20wiki&f=false).

Comment: In what context? You use "professionally", what cast does that put on the question? Did you mean "diplomatically"? Not enough information.

Comment: What profession?

Comment: @NigelJ: They're not mutually exclusive. Being caught *wrong-footed* means something slightly different from being caught *flat-footed*. Also, the Corpus finds many more instances of *caught flat-footed*.

Comment: @Robusto Indeed. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caught+flat-footed%2Ccaught+wrong-footed&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaught%20flat%20-%20footed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20wrong%20-%20footed%3B%2Cc0) shows an overwhelming preference for 'flat'.

Comment: @NigelJ as I understand it, 'caught wrong-footed' is "I was prepared for A, but B happened instead"; where as 'caught flat-footed' is "I was not prepared at all, but something happened".

Answer (score 0):

I would think it could be used professionally, formally and informally.  depending on the audience.

caught **flat footed**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flat+footed)

> 1. Slow to react. Unprepared. Often used in the phrase "caught flat footed."

Comment: Please don't answer questions which can only be answered with opinions.